# In QGIS, is it possible to save or export a vector layer that has SVG markers as it's points?

Tags: qgis, point, svg, vector-layer

Using QGIS, I have created some points in a vector layer. I'm using SVG markers for them. I'd like to export or save this vector layer along with the SVG symbols for further use in a web application.
Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *layer files* store only references to symbols and data etc., and *geopackages* do not store symbols as far as I know, the only approach that I can imagine is the **qgis2web** plugin, which creates openlayers code or leaflet code rsp. It creates ready-to-use web applications, and store the svg symbols in a subdirectory of the application (if applies).